# Elastic Search Sort

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, elasticsearch

I have a table for some activities like

```
[
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Ram",
  "status": 1,
  "activity": "Poster Design"
},
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Ram",
  "status": 1,
  "activity": "Poster Design"
},
{
  "id": 124,
  "name": "Leo",
  "categories": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "status": 1,
  "activity": "Brochure"
},
{
  "id": 134,
  "name": "Levin",
  "categories": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "status": 1,
  "activity": "3D Printing"
}
```

]

I want to get this data from elastic search 5.5 by sorting on field activity, but I need all the data corresponding to name = "Ram" first and then remaining in a single query.

Comment: Any idea please share. Really Urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query to boost the result based on match for the filter(this case ram in name).

Following query should work for you

```
POST sort_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "boost": "5",
            "functions": [{
                "filter": {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "ram"
                    }
                },
                "random_score": {},
                "weight": 1000
            }],
            "score_mode": "max"
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "activity.keyword": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a bool query combined with the [should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause.
U will also need to use the [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) clause on your field.